# Polar coordinate axes

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, polarplot, axis

I am trying to create a set of polar coordinate axes using this code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-176,-176)(176,176)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar](128,360)
%    \psaxes[showorigin=true,xAxis=true,Dy=10,dy=25.6,Dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128.01)
%    \uput{0pt}[0](-160,0){{\large\itshape{H}}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I only want to create the inner "rings" every 32 units. Unfortunately, the above code places rings every 1 unit it seems. How do I fix this? Setting ticks=none has no effect.

[edit]

I  tried this as well.

```
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,Dx=32,dx=32](128,360)
```

The inner rings are now spaced properly, but there are too many of them extending past the outer rim. And the labels still increment for every 1 unit.

[edit]

I'm starting to think it's a pst-plot bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pst-plot}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-176pt,-176pt)(176pt,176pt)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,labels=y](128pt,360)
    \psaxes[Dx=32,dx=1cm,dy=1cm,Dy=32](128pt,128pt)
    \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the x-axis must be in the range of 0..128 units.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I voted this as the answer. But it seems buggy to have to use a workaround like this. And the styling is not as nice as Jake's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do this with PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=128,
    ytick distance=32,
    yticklabel shift=2pt
]
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```